# Analytic function or Non-analytic function in a Neural Network?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, analytic-functions, neural-networks

I'm working on the field of Complex and Hyper-complex Neural Networks. Therefore I see a lot of papers using both analytics and non-analytics functions without specific justifications. Therefore, I am wondering what is the theorical impact of both method on the behavior of a neural net ? Let's define the sigmoid function of a real : $$ \sigma(x)= \frac{1}{1+e(-x)}$$

It exist first a fully complex and analytic sigmoid activation function to a complex-number : $$z=x+iy$$ defined by :
$$ \sigma(z)= \frac{1}{1+e(-z)}$$

And also a non-analytic one :
$$ \sigma(z)= \frac{1}{1+e(-x)} + i\frac{1}{1+e(-y)}$$

Can someone explain me what are the intuitions behind the usage of both methods ? Is the analytic one only able to learn analytics functions ?

Thanks you !

Comment: It is unclear why you want to look at $z$ complex. Do you plan to use complex training data ? Then the obvious choice is to split the real and imaginary part and forget about complex analytic functions. The sigmoid is essentially a smooth approximation of $\text{sign}(x)$. If your neural network is a complex analytic function then it can learn only complex analytic functions whose shape are highly constrained (see the maximum modulus principle).

Comment: Well yes my inputs are complex and outputs are too. That's what tough about the capability of learning only analytic functions. Thanks !